# Eloquent select last row of group

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table:

```
id  name    factory
-------------------
1   apple   1
2   orange  2
3   banana  3
4   peach   1
```

I want to select values grouped by their `factory` value, and ordered by the ID.
So the query will return orange, banana and peach (without apple).

I have tried this:

```
$data = Fruit::groupBy('factory')->distinct()->get();
```

But it returns apple, orange and banana (instead of orange, banana and peach)

I've also tried ordering it by ID ascending but the results were the same just reversed.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
$data = Fruit::whereRaw('id IN (select MAX(id) FROM fruits GROUP BY factory)')->get();
```

Comment: Great answer worked for me